# REGEX with text and number both + salesforce validation

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a peculiar requirement where I should check the user should either enter valid email or a valid 10-digit number. 
I have the below solution created:

```
AND(
    NOT(REGEX ( UPPER ( MACYS_PreferredModeOfContactInformation__c ), "^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$")),
    NOT(REGEX( MACYS_PreferredModeOfContactInformation__c, '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})')),
    NOT(REGEX(MACYS_PreferredModeOfContactInformation__c, "(\\d){10}"))
)
```

But this solution will not work if I have below requirement:
**1234567890abc@xyz.com**

Comment: Validating email addresses tends to be folly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm analyzing your second Regex statement on debuggex.com and I'm not really sure what it's trying to accomplish. It basically says:

1) Any number of alphanumeric characters or _-.

2) An @ sign

And then one of:

either 3) exactly three groups of dot-separated lowercase letters with up to 3 characters each

or 4) Any number of groups of alphanumeric characters or - followed by a .

And then:

5) 2-4 alphabetic characters or up to 3 numeric characters.

So something like `abc@9.654` would be accepted as a valid input and I doubt this is your intention.

Also be aware that your first Regex which appears to target e-mails more clearly is outdated because top-level domains can now exceed 4 characters.

If you are having trouble with Regex matches you may find a visualization tool like Debuggex to be very valuable. The Regex I'm currently using for e-mails is:

`^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,63}$`

This is still not infallible (e.g. it would match `abc@9...com`) but it's a first-order approximation.

If you have any other examples that illustrate needs I haven't grasped here, let me know. I am new to Regex myself but doing my best!

Comment: Yeah the [fully compliant](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) expression is 5558 characters long (for PHP, at least). [Recommended reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address). *It's also important to understand that validating it per the RFC tells you absolutely nothing about whether that address actually exists at the supplied domain, or whether the person entering the address is its true owner.* Also, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrUwP.png) appropriately captures the complexity.

Comment: Right, and really the purpose of a first-order validation is to ensure they did not make a very obvious error. So it's up to you to decide what is the appropriate threshold.